# Store a model temporarily in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, model

In a store app I'm working on I have a products route that shows all products and a product route that shows one product, pretty simple stuff. When the user is sent to the checkout route it sets the model to the model for the product controller. But if something goes wrong or the user refreshes that page for some reason, the model is obviously tossed out. How can I get that model to stay in the route until they transition out and not when they refresh?

Comment: Your question is somewhat confusing. Can you rephrase the last two sentences?

Comment: So I get to the products page and it loads all products from my model, I click on an item and go to the product route where I get a singular product from my model, then I click buy and I transition to the checkout route and set it's model equal to the model that the product route had, the singular model. However when the user refreshes that page the model is tossed out, I know why this happens but I am looking for a solution to this, something like storing it locally. But I want to trash it when they transition from the checkout route back to a different route.

Comment: Take a look at [`willTransition`](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/preventing-and-retrying-transitions/) - it's a hook that is fired when the user attempts to exit the route, in which you could destroy a checkout/order model that you previously created (and perhaps stored locally).

Comment: I think you want to persist the cart on the server or maybe use HTML5 local storage.